# Remove items from map

Tags: map, null, duplicate-value, remove

I have a map which contains some information about opportunities and sales.

| AccId | Revenue | Amount | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 10000 | 500 |
| 2 | 500 | 250 | 250 |
| 5 |  |  |  |
| 7 | 10 | 10 |  |
| 9 |  |  | 25 |

**How can I remove the item 5, because the Revenue *AND* Amount *AND* Sales are null.**

Below is my code to create the content of the map.

```
public void getcreatemaps() {           
    // Create a map of wrapper
    Map<Id, ResultWrapper> mapAccountIdToWrapper = new Map<Id, ResultWrapper>();
    
    // Create a set of Account Id
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();       
    
    // Fill the wrapper map and the set of AccountIds from Account
    for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = '0050X000006E88bQAC' ORDER BY Name]) {
        accountIds.add(acc.Id);
        ResultWrapper wrap = new ResultWrapper();
        wrap.AccId = acc.Id;
        wrap.AccName = acc.Name;
        mapAccountIdToWrapper.put(wrap.AccId, wrap);
    }           
    
    // for each value in the map, set revenue and amount
    for(AggregateResult MYoppAr :[SELECT AccountId AccId, Sum(ExpectedRevenue) MyRev, Sum(Amount) MyFin FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND OwnerId = '0050X000006E88bQAC' AND CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND (IsClosed = false OR IsWon = true) GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        Id accountId = (Id) MYoppAr.get('AccId');
        ResultWrapper combinedResult = mapAccountIdToWrapper.get(accountId);
        combinedResult.MyExpectedRevenue  = (Decimal)MYoppAr.get('MyRev');
        combinedResult.MyAmount           = (Decimal)MYoppAr.get('MyFin');
    }

// for each value in the map, set sales
for(AggregateResult MYsalAr :[SELECT Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__c AccId, Sum(BWS_Brutto__c) MyBWS FROM Umsatz__c WHERE Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__c IN :accountIds AND Berater__c = '0050X000006E88bQAC' AND Bewertungsmonat__c = THIS_YEAR GROUP BY Einzelrisiko__r.Gruppenvertrag__r.Unternehmen__c]) {            
    Id accountId = (Id) MYsalAr.get('AccId');
    ResultWrapper combinedResult = mapAccountIdToWrapper.get(accountId);
    combinedResult.MySales = (Decimal) MYsalAr.get('MyBWS');         
}            
    resultList = mapAccountIdToWrapper.values();
}
```

**EDIT 05.11.2021**

I tried to loop through the map, but I don't know how can I check the value of the different values in the map? Below is my example, but I get an error.
*Variable does not exist: MyExpectedRevenue*

```
for (String key : mapAccountIdToWrapper.keyset()) {
    if(key.MyExprectedRevenue = Null) {
        MapAccountIdToWrapper.remove(key);                
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that built these maps, not really sure how we can help you. I know what you have now is *definitely* wrong, though. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: The best approach would be to test your conditions during creation of the maps.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added the code to get the information for the map.

Comment: Have you tried looping through the map keys and using the `remove()` method where applicable?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes, but I don't know how. I edited my question and added my loop code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues I see.

In using the key set(). You need to get the value and then get the field.  Code below adds the get.  You can also get the Map values directly using map.values().

Second issue you need == instead of = in your comparison. Hope this helps.

```
for (String key : mapAccountIdToWrapper.keyset()) {
    if(mapAccountIdToWrapper.get(key).MyExprectedRevenue == Null) {
        MapAccountIdToWrapper.remove(key);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Also… to loop though all the fields you could either create a  method in the class that checks for the values of the fields.. or if that is too OOP for you could use   GetPopulatedFieldsAsMap… you could see if the map keyset() contains the fields you are interest in, if not it would remove the item from the map wrapper 

From the Sobject class: getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()
Returns a map of populated field names and their corresponding values. The map contains only the fields that have been populated in memory for the SObject instance

Comment: If the Sobject class only has the 4 fields you could also just check the size of the getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() and remove anything with a size of less than 2